# Suppressing page break at specific location

Tags: sectioning, formatting, titlesec

Is it possible to suppress a page break at one instance in a document?

Specifically, I am looking to stop a page break that is occurring between a `\part` and `\chapter`.

I am using a book class.

Comment: how does this question differ from [Chapter on same page as Part](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335494/579)?  that said, in all book classes that i'm familiar with, `\chapter` includes in its definition a break to a new (usually right-hand) page, so avoiding such a break would require redefinition of `\chapter`, or an alternate definition to be used only in this particular situation.  (i'd go with a dedicated alternate definition if i were faced with this problem.)

Comment: Thanks for your response barbara. Isthere anyway to suppress the page break from the chapter command in just one instance? THank you

Comment: The best trick, as stated, is to make a custom version of (say) `\chapter` that copies it exactly but omits the part about starting a new page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's the purpose of this, but here is a way to do what you want:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@partstarted
\xpatchcmd{\part}{\null\vfil}{\vspace*{0pt}}{}{} % don't fill above part title 
\renewcommand\@endpart{\global\@partstartedtrue} % don't fill below part title
\xpatchcmd{\chapter}
  {\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}
  {\if@partstarted\global\@partstartedfalse\else
   \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi\fi}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\part{Part title}

\chapter{Chapter title}

\chapter{Chapter title}

\end{document}
```

The frame is just to show the appearance in context.

[image]